# Problem in creation MDB Queue connection at Jboss StartUp

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jms, message-queue, jboss-mdb

I am not able to create a Queue connection in JBOSS4.2.3GA Version & Java1.5, as I am using MDB as per the below details.

I am putting this MDB in a jar file(named utsJar.jar) and copied it in deploy folder of JBOSS, In the test env. this MDB works well

but in another env. [ env settings and jboss/java ver is same ] it is throwing error at jboss start up [attached below ]. I have searched

for this error but couldn't find any solution till now; was there any issue of port confict or something related with configurations ?

UTSMessageListner.java >>

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig =

{

@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),

@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="queue/UTSQueue")

})


@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)

public class UTSMessageListner implements MessageListener

{

public void onMessage(Message msg)

{

ObjectMessage objmsg = (ObjectMessage) msg;

try

{

UTSListVO utsMessageListVO = (UTSListVO) objmsg.getObject();


if(utsMessageListVO.getUtsMessageList()!=null) {

UtsWebServiceLogger.logMessage("UTSMessageListner:onMessage: SIZE Of UTSMessage List =[" +utsMessageListVO.getUtsMessageList().size() + "]");

UTSDataLayerImpl.getInstance().insertUTSMessage(utsMessageListVO);

}

else {

UtsWebServiceLogger.logMessage("UTSMessageListner:onMessage: Message List is NULL");

}

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

UtsWebServiceLogger.logMessage("UTSMessageListner:onMessage: Error Receiving Message"+ExceptionUtility.getStackTrace(ex));

}

}

}
```

[ I have also attached whole server.log as an attach] ///

///////////////////////////////// Error Trace is Below while starting the server ///////////////////////////

```
2010-03-12 07:05:40,061 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer] Could not find the queue destination-jndi-name=queue/UTSQueue
2010-03-12 07:05:40,061 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer] destination not found: queue/UTSQueue reason: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: queue not bound
2010-03-12 07:05:40,061 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer] creating a new temporary destination: queue/UTSQueue
2010-03-12 07:05:40,071 WARN  [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.j2ee:ear=uts.ear,jar=utsJar.jar,name=UTSMessageListner,service=EJB3
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.DestinationManager.createDestination(DestinationManager.java:336)
at org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.DestinationManager.createQueue(DestinationManager.java:293)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.ejb3.JmxClientKernelAbstraction.invoke(JmxClientKernelAbstraction.java:44)
at org.jboss.ejb3.jms.DestinationManagerJMSDestinationFactory.createDestination(DestinationManagerJMSDestinationFactory.java:75)
at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.createTemporaryDestination(MessagingContainer.java:573)
at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.createDestination(MessagingContainer.java:512)
at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.innerCreateQueue(MessagingContainer.java:438)
at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.jmsCreate(MessagingContainer.java:400)
at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.innerStart(MessagingContainer.java:166)
at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.start(MessagingContainer.java:152)
at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MDB.start(MDB.java:126)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.ejb3.ServiceDelegateWrapper.startService(ServiceDelegateWrapper.java:103)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy53.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.ejb3.JmxKernelAbstraction.install(JmxKernelAbstraction.java:120)
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.registerEJBContainer(Ejb3Deployment.java:301)
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.start(Ejb3Deployment.java:362)
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Module.startService(Ejb3Module.java:91)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy33.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.ejb3.EJB3Deployer.start(EJB3Deployer.java:512)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy34.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

---

Still I am not able to create Queue, this time error occured "Queue Already Exists", I have made entry in jboss-web.xml and jbossmq-destinations-service.xml.

Strange thing is that in my developemnt enviornment i dont have any entries of Queue name in the files you mentioned instead of i have entry in application.xml file of my ear as follows - >

utsJar.jar // Which contains utsMessageLister.class file

which works fine for me in developemt enviourment and it will create a UtsQueue for me, but in other enviournment i am facing the issue.

Please suggest & thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

add a dependency to the MDB as below

```
@Depends ("jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=UtsQueue")
```

this will create the queue before the ejb container deploys the MDB.

declare the queue mbean in jboss-service.xml

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue"
        name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=UtsQueue">            
        <depends optional-attribute-name="DestinationManager">jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager
        </depends>
</mbean>
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is due to in fact that you try to connect your MDB to a queue that doesn't exist (UTSQueue).

Have you try to define your queue in the jboss.xml like that:

```
<jboss> 
    <enterprise-beans> 
        <message-driven> 
            <ejb-name>UTSMessageListner</ejb-name> 
            <destination-jndi-name>queue/UTSQueue</destination-jndi-name> 
        </message-driven> 
    </enterprise-beans> 
</jboss>
```

and add this to the jbossmq-destinations-service.xml:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue" 
      name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=UTSQueue"> 
</mbean>
```

After watch in the administration panel of Jboss if this queue appear.

For more information on how create a queue in jboss you can read this: [JMS and Message-Driven Beans](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/mdb.html)

Comment: Eclipse is giving an error when I try to add: message-driven tag in the jboss.xml of my project